# Remove content after link

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've this code :

```html
<span>
   <a href="#">Hello world</a>
   »
</span>
```

I want delete `»` after the link.

I try this but it does not work.

```
jQuery(function ($) {

   $('span a').nextAll('»').remove();

});
```

Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/stanze/9stppkqv/1/), by the help of text node.

```
$("span").contents().filter(function () 
    {
       return this.nodeType != 1;
    })
.remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution si to delete the last child of the span for that

```
$('span').contents().last().remove()
```

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('button').click(function(){
    $('span').contents().last().remove();
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Remove</button>
<span>
   <a href="#">Hello world</a>
   »
</span>
```

---

To delete the next sibling of `a`

```
$($('span a')[0].nextSibling).remove()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this with only css: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qt0ybpm7/2/)**

```
<span>
   <a href="#">Hello world</a>
    <span> » </span>
</span>
```

CSS:

```
span>span{
   display:none;

}
```